# Use SCR dimming info to feed 1-10VDC line

Tags: led, dimming, scr

Hello I am modifying an electronic lighting fixture to use LED instead. I have everything I need already, 80W LED, Power Supply, etc. There are just two issues I cannot resolve.

The original fixture uses SCR dimming chip (controlled by electronics/computer) to power and dim a 24VAC Halogen Bulb at 250 Watts. The LED Driver accepts a DC Voltage between 1-12VDC. Im trying to somehow get that dimming information from the SCR, inputs, or outputs and convert it to 1-12VDC depending on the dimming amount fed into the SCR.

The second issue may be easier.. Since im powering the LED seperately, it needs to know when to turn on and off. I figure some type of circuit which can detect ANY voltage from the 24V halogen bulb leads  to and trigger the LED power supply to turn on. I know relays do this but from my understanding relays need a constant control voltage.

The schematic for the dimmer circuit is here (Page 14 labeled dimmer).. I do see +5V and "MOC_EN" not sure what that means or if it can be used
https://www.highend.com/pub/products/automated_luminaires/Trackspot/Schematic/Tspotr15.pdf

Comment: an SCR dimmer will only work with an AC source

Comment: Yes the source is 24VAC i believe.. im trying to use the output information to feed 1-12VDC

Comment: On your unit -- is the signal on pin 5 of IC2 (DIM_EN) connected directly to pin 2 of IC33 (MOC_EN)? Or is there some circuitry between them?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have uploaded a photo of the PCB I have circled the two SCR's and the IC33 chip..
http://savinet.net/img/ts1.jpg

Comment: @TimDavis -- can you use your continuity tester to "buzz out" the connection from Pin 5 IC2 to Pin 2 IC33?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ... Looks like IC2 is a big 40 Pin chip.. Anyways there is no coninuity from Pin 5 IC2 and Pin 2 IC33

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel .. when running that same test with the unit powered up, the multimeter flashes 186OHM on contact then goes back to zero.. actually when using the arrow setting on the multimeter it stays at 211

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders - this is a request for a specific solution BUT can be applied to many similar ones where derivation of an LED control signal from existing equipment is desired.

Comment: @TimDavis -- why are you doing it with the unit *powered on*?!  Turn the unit off and try the test again...you don't do resistance or continuity checks on a turned-on device!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I thought there may be a difference.. im a software engineer, not electronics engineer but hopefully dont fry anything.. or myself

Comment: @TimDavis -- sorry, missed your earlier comment re: the turned-off test results btw.  And yeah, take a resistance measurement there.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel with the unit off, for pin 2 on IC33 to pin 5 on IC2 1.6 flashes quickly on the screen then goes to "0L". I also tried pins 1 and 6 on IC33 and they both stay at 1.2 and 1.6 but not pin two only flashes

Comment: @TimDavis -- check a known-good resistor with your multimeter (just making sure you didn't kill it by trying to use the ohms function on a live circuit :)

Comment: the multimeter is working properly

Comment: @TimDavis Please mentally extract and trash the snarky parts of my comments below and note the technical advice. IC33 is the dimmer control opto so the input signal must be a dimmin related signal. It is probably either phase controlled PWM or cycle by cycle PWM. Smoothing it will give a smooth dimming signal but not necessarily linear as it may be shaped to allow for lamp response BUT maybe not as they MAY use lighting operator brain feedback for that. | ALSO my suggestion re a rectified signal from the map out with a resistor load also has a very good chance of working. ...

Comment: ... It's easy cheap quick and simple to try. Diode from one lamp leg or two diodes - one per leg - both with anode to lamp power and cathode (bar on diode) to out. Join cathodes if two diodes.  Take this via a resistor to ground. Put cap across resistor. DC meter across resistor will vary with "brightness".  DC wll need dividing down to 12V max and MAY need shaping to linearlise lamp response. Maybe not. EASY to try.

Comment: See added circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCteTZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A problem (of sorts) is that the AC supply is notionally isolated from the logic supply - see diagram below - BUT if it is the same supply as on page 14 this is not a problem. . Two mains choices to get dimming information are

- Use the signal between (+5V - MOC_EN) to provide the dimming information remotely.
- Put a load on the dimmer output and derive the dimming signal from there.

IC33 is an optocoupler. By using an identical or similar optocoupler with input connected from +5V to MOC_EN via a suitable resistor. I cannot see where MOVC_EN is derived from but it will probably allow a second opto to be used - one with more sensitivity and a larger resistor would help minimise extra load.

The dimmer shows a 24 VAC signal on page 14, used to supply power via a bridge rectifier to the logic circuitry. If this is the same as the one used for the map in the circuit below then this output can be used as a dimming voltage source.

**Using AC lamp output for dimming signal source:**

Connect a single diode (Dl)from (or a bridge rectifier for less ripple) from lamp output to a resistor (Rl) to ground. Add a "suitable" capacitor (Cl) across Rl. Rl should be as large as works OK. ie a resistor giving full lap load will replicate the lamp voltage but dissipate as much power as the map. Probably a 100 Ohm to 1k resistor will work. 1k to 10k may. 10k is best if it works. Size wattage to suit. Cl filters this to a DC level. Using a bridge rectifier (see page 14 BR1 as an example) will provide a smoother DC signal. Extra filtering may well be needed - this can be discussed if this answer looks useful. System gain control or an external potentiometer (or both) will control relative brightness.

On off control can be provided by detecting a minimum DC level for LED turn-on (as you suggested).
**Try this** - see text below and in comments

[image]

---

**However -** an "easy" possible solution (depends on LED power voltage) would be to power the LEDs directly from the existing output using the existing AC rectified with a bridge rectifier. I assume the LEDs use 12VDC for main powering - maybe not. If V_LED_power is >> 30V then the following does not work.
LEDs would either need to accept up to 24 VDC or the system arranged to "not overdo it". A one resistor addition to the optocoupler drive would allow lower maximum output voltage levels. As the original unit can drive 250W at 24 VAC, driving a 12VDC 80W load would work.

Comment: THe driver will likely try to maintain a constant current in the face of decreasing voltage, up until it drops out, unfortunately...hence the 0-10V dim input on it.  Tapping the MOC_EN signal's along the right line of thought, at least...but I'm not sure if that's a direct drive from the micro in his case; the schematic may simply have a glitch in the netnames (there's a DIM_EN coming from the micro, but no MOC_EN or DIM_EN anywhere else in the schematic I can find), or something else fishy may be going on that I haven't seen.

Comment: Also, your approach with rectifying and voltage-dividing the phase-controlled output could work as well -- I suspect that'd be nonlinear though, although my idea (using the zero-cross and dim enable signals to generate PWM which is then filtered to generate 0-10V or w/e analog signal is needed) probably isn't any better on linearity...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Driver? What driver ? :-) - I had in mind driving the LEDs directly if their (unspecified) voltage allowed. | DIM_EN! - bother :-) - I went through the sheets several times. | Regardless of where it's from MOC_EN does what you want - but yes, DIM_EN sounds good. Linearity can be addressed next :-) (ie writing lonnnnnnnng answers that are rejected at a glance due to some unknown factor "gets annoying).

Comment: The OP is using a driver (LED power supply) for this job...and yeah, linearity can be addressed next :)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The LED Chip DC Forward Current(IF): 2400mA
Intensity Luminous(IV): 7500-8000LM
DC Forward Voltage(VF): DC 28.0-36.0v .. Id love to be able to power the LED Directly but I was told they need a constant current

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The OP has bought a LED driver for this job - yes. Whether he needs it is TBD. Certainly 'go with the flow' is probably to derive a dimming signal and use the driver. He now has supplied LED specs. | You could ... :-) | Nah. Use the dimmer module :-)

Comment: @TimDavis The driver module + derived dimmer signal is safer. You could probably drive it directly with a little extra "glue" BUT the LED sits up towards the top end of the original driver range (24VAC ~= 34V peak and a bit less loaded ) so LED would be out for low volumes and on in small range near top of original drive range. Using driver makes it easier. | Try by diode plus resistor plus cap plus pot and start with a meter to see how it works. IF you can get a reasonably smooth V control variation it may be all you need.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon & ThreePhaseEel thanks for your answer comments.. To be clear are we abandoning trying to get dimming from 24VAC line? I think the issue is, and why I purchased the driver is because LED's don't dim. Decreasing their voltage only causes them to flicker and go out. Since these are used for stage lighting, the dimming must be smooth and accurate. So does your suggestion mean from MOC/DIM_EN? or IC33/IC2?

Comment: Also I wanted to add that there is one bit of info maybe necessary. All functions (Pan, Zoom, Dim, Shutter, are controlled by DMX Protocol) there is a chip I believe IC37 that manages this, also "DIM" is on channel 6 of the DMX. This unit accepts a control voltage 0-12V much like the LED so maybe there is an internal control voltage for dimming

Comment: @TimDavis There is a typos in your last comment. Where you accidentally wrote "All functions (Pan, Zoom, Dim, Shutter, are controlled by DMX Protocol) there is a chip I believe IC37 that manages this, also "DIM" is on channel 6 of the DMX." you obviously really intended to write "now I'll tell you the real situation and my real requirement so you'll see that mention of the Trackspot was just be joking with you. ||| OK. Let's start again. WHAT IS THE real QUESTION. What are you REALLY trying to do.  Do you really want a DMX to LED decoder or will the spot still be used but with the ...

Comment: @TimDavis ... LED light source but pan etc still controlled as before. IC37 is essentially irrelevant. IC2 is what counts (it's the microcontroller so that is no help) . AISA [As I said above] the dimming signal appears on IC33 page 13 and be read using and opto AISA or directly if desired. Also AISA as noted by Mr Eel MOC_EN may be connected to DIM_EN and a meter will tell you. Also, my suggestion re 24AC derivation of LED dim signal may be a good one. AND it is easy for you to try. If lamp dims smoothly now you can make a smooth control signal. It MAY need some (probably easy) curve shaping.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for the circuit diagram. All the pan, zoom function would remain the same as LED's don't pan or zoom. Believe it or not there are readily available DMX chips out there that would be far easier to implement from scratch. I only mention the DMX channel but because studying the diagram more It looks to me like the "DIM_EN" is out of place for dimming on IC2 (could be a typo). IC2 seems to control higher order funtions such as the sensors, analog irq, selection knobs,etc.. While pan/zoom/dim etc are DMX specific and controlled by IC37

Comment: @TimDavis IC37 is the EROM memory IC for the processor. By itself it is as dumb as an average doormat and would not know a DMX signal if it wiped its feet on it. IC2 is the processor whose program is stored in the doormat. | If P4 lampout on page 13 is the lamp out (sounds legit) and not a Dormouse then IC33 **is** the optocoupler that controls dimming and MOC_EN **IS** the dimming control signal. Trace MOC_EN to source (probably DIM_EN) or whatever or tap off at MOC_EN as I have said N times. Do not wake the Dormouse. [[Or should I just give up?]].

Comment: @RussellMcMahon the diagram above uses a POT for control? Am I correct to assume that that will not necessarily be needed as the signal input is already being dimmed? I will try that but One more dumb question is could I tap the leads of MOC_EN without removing the IC?

Comment: @TimDavis  Pot is to fine tune level. My original trial method (above) did not need the pot to start to see how it goes. As at full cry lamp is at 24 VAC, the rectified DC will be 30v+. if you want 10v in that condition you  need to divide it. Pot fine tunes that but is not essential if you use a 2 resistor divider. | I covered how to parallel a 2nd opto in text above.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I purchased a Bridge Rectifier and get 30VDC output from lamp, the voltage also drops as expected when dimming (I don't have oscilliscope). Im still playing with resistors to get the right reduced 12V voltage.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  but in the mean time I got some answers from the boards manufacturer.. Perhaps this can help 

"DIM_EN is pin 5 on the processor (80C31), this goes to pin 1 of IC39. IC 39 inverts the signal, and feeds pin 13 of IC25, a NAND gate. Pin 12 of this NAND gate is fed from pin 4 of IC39, the inverted +24dc ( padded by a 10K resistor) going to the fan. When pins 12 and 13 of IC25 go low, pin 11 also goes low, this is MOC_EN, connected to pin 2 of the lamp control opto. This circuit prevents the lamp from operating if the fan is not."

Comment: @TimDavis If you can show me where on the diagrams you say relate IC25/11 12 13 or IC39 / 4 are it would help. | Principal is understood. ||| IF the map dimmer SCR2 shown on page 13 are essentially the same as what you have then trying the several things I have suggested would give some results to discuss. | Have you tried any of the things I suggested. | I see now tyhat at least one solution you were given on AAC site was much the same as my external output suggestion. Have you tried his or my suggestions? (Mine takes 2 diodes, a few resistors and a meter to test.

Comment: @TimDavis Whoops - sorry :-( - just read your comment re resistors and dimming. 2 diodes will do as per my diagram but bridge OK and allows non earth reference. Cap across resistor provides smoother DC. A post filter probably needed for smooth control but we can come to that.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon . Yes I completed the circuit with a smaller cap (47uf) (first one was way too big and took minutes to charge lol) that is making the voltage jump from 24vdc to 30vdc. I made a voltage divider with 3 resistors bringing it down to 10VDC, and again it changes with dimming on fixture. However I am now looking into PWM based LED Drivers cause the supplier is backordered. So I purchased an Audrino board but the PWM is flickering not sure if thats due to lack of a "post filter" or some other issue with the loop in Audrino.  But this does look like a viable solution. Thanks

Comment: Back again! Looking at my last comments you can tell I was, and still am sort of all over the place, this seems like a common problem converting triac to led, some IC's do it but they generally designed for 110/220V. 

I decided it easier to separate the triac decoding from the PWM generation, only questions left are what happens at low duty cycles, would there be enough juice for a LED at 5% duty cycle? and now its just of a question of boosting 32V to 35V and 3A constant current circuit, or aftermarket boost/constant current driver